# Reverse engineered Arguments in Dapper Dynamic parameters list

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm curently create some test on the controller of a MVC web site.

I use Dapper to get data from BDD through a single access point standardized.

For the test, I mock the data access, of course, but I need to get the _value of one of the parameters passed into the DynamicParameters, to know if I get all data from the queried table or only one based on a code.

Problem is I don't know hot to get _value porperty from a dynamic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have the solution.

As I had to create a personalized data type (JsonBParameter) I simply add a GetParameter that return the value in the class.... So easy :(